# How to tell Google (Cyren) Antivirus that it Incorrectly detected as malware/malicious my software?

Tags: antivirus

All of a sudden Google started to say my application is a virus. Does anyone know the best way to reach out to them and to have a "closer" look? Microsoft has a SmartScreen submission page where you can upload your application and ask them to review it, and it works great & fast...

Every single antivrus other than Google's Cyren says my application is safe, including: AVG, ESET-NOD32, Mailware Bytes, McAfee, Symantec, Webroot, BitDefender, and etc... (I just listed the "famous" ones)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cyren currently does have a way to submit such samples. They accept submissions via E-mail (with zipped and password-protected attachment), and via FTP.

For details, please see: https://www.cyren.com/support/reporting-av-misclassifications

---

Please note that Cyren is not owned by Google, and VirusTotal is in fact listing it as a separate positive result. I was unable to find what Google product is used. My best guess would be Google's [SafeBrowsing](https://safebrowsing.google.com/).